# ¿Dónde puedo descargar la librería php xmlrpc.so?

Tags: php

estoy en OSX y necesito descargar la librería xmlrpc. Esta tarea en ubuntu u otra distribución con un apt-get se soluciona fácil la instalación de la extensión pero en OSX no consigo instalarlo.

He probado con 
`brew install xmlrpc-c`
pero me descarga una carpeta y no el .so

He buscado por internet por si encontraba para descargarlo y tampoco.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

En esta página puedes descargarte las versiones 4.2 y 3.1 de esa librería:

> http://gggeek.github.io/phpxmlrpc/

Pruebalo y me comentas.

Comment: Gracias. Sí, esa página la he visto pero no me descarga el .so para añadirlo como extensión en el php.ini. Lo ideal que busco es eso. Hay alguna manera de encontrar esa extensión?

Comment: Tienes un archivo llamado "INSTALL.md" donde te explica como ponerlo en marcha. Siguiendolo se pone en marcha.

Comment: Al final he utilizado la librería externa `composer require phpxmlrpc/phpxmlrpc`. La añadí a mi composer.json y donde lo necesitaba hice un `use PhpXmlRpc\Request;`y listo. Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.